# Not able to App Only Authentication with Power BI Embedding using service principal

Tags: powerbi-embedded

```
I am using app only authentication with power bi embedding and following below steps:

1. Registered an App in Azure Active Directory and capture an application ID,
 an application secret, and the service principal object ID.
2. Create a security group in Azure Active Directory (AAD).
3. In Power BI admin, enable service principal in the Developer settings 
add the security group
4. Add the service principal as an admin to the workspace
But I am getting error "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'"
```

Please see pic how i enabled things.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create new workspaces. If you have existing ones you will have to migrate them to new ones.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/use-power-bi-api-with-service-principal-preview/

See section "How to migrate Power BI Embedded to work with service principal"